# Configure AWS cognito for federated sign-in to get authenticated through microsoft account (live.com)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

I'm trying to configure my AWS cognito User pool for federated sign-in for microsoft users. I've followed this article.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-amazon-cognito-for-federated-authentication-using-azure-ad/

This authentication flow is working only for the users who are associated with specific enterprise application created inside Azure AD. I have multiple clients who are having their own Azure AD instances for maintaining their users and handling authentication. I need to onboard those users in my application using federated sign-in. Hence I'm trying to give a generic button to end users to `Login with Microsoft`. Can someone please suggest the direction?